# Merging XML nodes into one comma delimited node

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes

I'm trying to combine several nodes of the same type using XSLT with Saxon on a mac.

Using what I've found so far on SO i've come up with the following...

A simplified version is this:

**Input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <other>y</other>
    <notarget>x</notarget>
    <target>red</target>
    <target>green</target>
    <target>blue</target>
  </product>
  <product>
    <id>2</id>
    <other>y</other>
    <notarget>x</notarget>
    <target>red</target>
    <target>orange</target>
    <target>yellow</target>
  </product>
  <product>
    <id>3</id>
    <other>y</other>
    <notarget>x</notarget>
    <target>yellow</target>
    <target>purple</target>
    <target>green</target>
  </product>
</products>
```

**transform.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <products>
      <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <other>y</other>
        <notarget>x</notarget>
        <target><xsl:value-of select="string-join(//target/text(), ',')" /></target>
      </product>
    </products>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**current output.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
   <product>
      <id>1</id>
      <other>y</other>
      <notarget>x</notarget>
      <target>red,green,blue,red,orange,yellow,yellow,purple,green</target>
   </product>
</products>
```

But it's combining all the nodes into a single 'product', what I want is this:

**desired output.xml**

```
<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <other>y</other>
    <notarget>x</notarget>
    <target>red, green, blue</target>
  </product>
  <product>
    <id>2</id>
    <other>y</other>
    <notarget>x</notarget>
    <target>red, orange, yellow</target>
  </product>
  <product>
    <id>3</id>
    <other>y</other>
    <notarget>x</notarget>
    <target>yellow, purple, green</target>
  </product>
</products>
```

I'm using the following command in terminal:

`saxon -s:input.xml -xsl:transform.xsl -o:output.xml '!indent=yes'`

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <products>
        <xsl:for-each select="product">
            <product>
                <xsl:copy-of select="* except target" />
                <target>
                    <xsl:value-of select="target" separator=", "/>
                </target>
            </product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </products>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LUY/1